# Add test user to the sudoers file, to run ifconfig

Tags: command-line, sudo, root

I would like to see the `ifconfig` file with test user (under Linux Debian) that's why I have used the sudo task, but the terminal said that: test is not in the `sudoers` file. How can I take the test user in the `sudoers` file?

I've tried the `/etc/pamd/su` but it is not found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sudeoers` file is usually located at `/etc/sudoers`.

You need administrative privileges to edit this file. Editing it directly is strongly discouraged: you could irrevocably damage your system in case of syntax errors.

The `visudo` tool is provided with the `sudo` package for safe editing. It will automatically check file's consistency before saving and abort on syntax errors.

`visudo` invokes the text editor set in the EDITOR environment variable, or `vi` otherwise. For instance, if you want to invoke Emacs instead:

```
$ EDITOR=emacs visudo
```

Once you have the editor fired up, you want to add the following line at the User privilege section:

```
test <host>=(ALL) /sbin/ifconfig
```

or, if you do not want to get prompted for a test's password

```
test <host>=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig
```

You need to replace  by your machine hostname, or 'ALL' if you want the privilege to apply on any machine.

See the man pages: `sudoers(5)`, `sudo(8)` and `visudo(8)` for the complete documentation.

Comment: That's correct, but not the right solution here. Running `ifconfig` does not require root.

Comment: The question surprised me as well and requires clarification.

Answer (score 4):

The `ifconfig` command is not included in users PATH env variable. So you can either `/sbin/ifconfig` or modify the `PATH` variable to include `sbin` into your users path.

Add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

source `~/.bashrc` using, `. ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bashrc` or open e new terminal which will source `~/.bashrc` file automagically